# Microsoft Graph - calendarview filter case-insensitive tolower

Tags: microsoft-graph-calendar

I need to filter calendar views on their *case insensitive* subject as returned by Microsoft Graph API.

What I have tried so far:

- I have confirmed that a case sensitive filter functions: `filter=startswith(subject,'mystring')`
- I get an error when I add `tolower` to my query string:  `filter=startswith(tolower(subject),'mystring')`
- I even get an error by just using teh `tolower` function in the filter: `filter=tolower(subject) eq 'mywholestring'` which I think might indicate that `tolower` is not suported.
- Yet I found broad use of tolower in the OneNote documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/onenote-get-content

This is the OData reference: https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752358

Comment: Have you managed to fix that issue, because I need tolower for case-insensitive filtration but it returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

I also have hard times with MS Graph case sensitivity, but here is a temporary workaround that I'm using:

```
https://my.site.name/_api/web/siteusers?$filter=substringof('Adam', Title) or substringof('adam', Title)
```

Maybe that will give you some ideas.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).